# How to check which classes act on an app feature?

Tags: java, class, android-studio, android-emulator

Using android studio, if I run an app on an emulator, and I click on features, how can I know which classes in my code are currently acting?

Comment: Your question isn't clear... Do you mean detecting what class is being run at the moment? Do you have any idea of how many background classes act during the run of your app?

Comment: yes that's what I am asking. I don't what classes run at each moment. It is a very large app.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an **Object Oriented Programming Language**.. In simple terms, this means Java code is pretty much objects calling other objects to do stuff. Therefore, when an android app is being run, many classes are actually simultaneously being run/called (or as you put it: *acting*).

But there's still a simple hack you can use to know the classes being run at the moment (*among the classes you wrote*):
I'd suggest you **log the entry point of every class you want to monitor**. For example, let's assume you have an app with three classes, in the entry point of each of the classes (be it an `onCreate()`, a custom class constructor or method), you can simply just log so you can monitor in your logcat.

Practically, when you use the method above, you get logs every time a new class is currently on focus.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!